# truffle flattener cannot find part of path

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain, erc-721

I am trying to flatten a solidity file but I keep getting cannot find part of path error as shown below

```
out-file : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Blockchain\bullrun\src\contracts\ERC721.sol'.
At line:1 char:1
+ truffle-flattener ./node_modules\@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

[image]

The command Im trying to run is truffle-flattener ./node_modules@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol > src/contracts/ERC721.sol. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the command

Comment: Please do not screenshot errors, but use text copy-paste and code formatting.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder from @openzeppelin from node_modules folder and paste it in the buildrun folder then, run the truffle-flattener